# Test automation tool for an Android app

Tags: android, command-line, software-testing, mobile, unit-tests

[Android monkey tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html) is great!
With one line of script, it launch your app and perform automation tests:

```
adb shell monkey -p my.greate.package + -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -s 123 --pct-touch 99 --throttle 20 -v 1000
```

You can configure it to do many things, in the above example I start an app by package name, restrict the monkey for touch events only. It will do 1000 touch events with 20 millisecond interval in between them.

---

However this tool is not enough for me. I need some thing without predefined or recorded tests, that I can just launch. But the monkey does not see the screen components, it clicks randomly on the screen, and some times there are buttons that it never finds.

I saw [this](http://www.testingtools.com/mobile-testing/) site with lots of alternatives, but none that is instant launch without pre-configurations.

Help me out here, how do I make my monkey smarter or find a better alternative?

Comment: So you want to launch it, without any (predefined or recorded) tests?  How will it get tested in that circumstance, and what kind of report are you hoping to see?

Comment: I got other tools for reporting, I just need it to be able to navigate threw the  app, without knowing it.

Comment: I don't understand.  You want to exercise the application, without knowing how it works?   If the application has any internal state, you can't do that.

Comment: @IraBaxter I want to maximize my success rate. Obviously there are apps that I want be able to navigate in.

Comment: This sounds a lot like unit tests of a function with random arguments.  The first few may different enough to cause different behaviors, but in general the input divides into many equivalence classes and most of the random argument values don't produce new behavior.  Why do you think this works?

Comment: @IraBaxter MY goal is to navigate in apps, how functions are related in here? Any way if you want to make a discussion about this, open a chat room

Comment: Random inputs to functions is an analog to random inputs on the screen.  And the former is long known by the testing community to be ineffective.  Just doesn't seem like pursuing random input will be effective.  No need for chat room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sikuli X](http://sikulix.com/) to automate anything that you can see on your PC screen including using image recognition to find specific buttons to click on regardless of the actual position on the screen.  This of course can include anything that is occurring on in the emulation environment or is repeated to the PC screen from an actual device.

You can click, double click, check results, type text into fields, etc., including launching programs.

It is script-able in python or java script.

Comment: This looks interesting. In my case I need to test a lot of applications that I didn't saw before. Do you think it will be useful for me? Because I am not sure what kind of script I can put there, except limiting the interaction area to my emulator screen. Can Sikuli X recognize buttons or shapes?

Comment: Sikuli recognises __anything__ on the screen and can be quickly and easily "trained" - it is amazingly easy to use.

Comment: Ok, I give it a try, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Ranorex is on the website you mentioned, but I think it does exactly what you want. You can use image-based recognition as well as XPath, a powerful identifier of UI elements. Ranorex contains a lot of useful [test automation tools](http://www.ranorex.com/test-automation-tools.html), for instance Ranorex Spy which might be very interesting for you since it allows you to create snapshot files from GUI elements.

Comment: It requires me to code the UI detection logic by my self, and then some how simulate event according to my detection results. So while there is some simplicity with XPath I will prefer opnecl for that task. But ultimately I prefer to use some thing that already does that...